# What is the equivalent of forwarding DLLs in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, dll, shim

I have a dynamic library that changes name across major versions i.e. version 3 was named lib3 and version 4 is named lib4, and so on.

I need to provide a shim lib3 that will allow an old application to use the new library in a transparent way, and most of the exported functions did not change across versions, so a forwarding DLL looks pretty good for the task on Windows.

Is there something equivalent on Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux equlivalent is rather easy. You can just use a symbolic link. For example, lib4 is the new library version, then you can create the following symbolic link:

```
ln -s lib4 lib3
```

Now, every time a program will need lib3 will automatically load lib4 as long as the interface
exported by the new version is equal to the old version, the program will not notice the difference.

I hope this helps.  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Ufortunately the interface changed across the major versions, this is wy we need to provide a shim layer to allow old applications to keep working in the new version. What I am looking for is a way to make the shim library forward most of the calls to the new library and handle the functions that changed in the shim.